# Proving that $\widehat{g*f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t^4}}$ and $g(t) = e^{-|t|}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

The question is as follows:

> Verify whether **the Fourier of the  convolution**: $f * g$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$? Where  $$f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + t^4}}~~and ~~~~g(t) = e^{-|t|}$$

$\textbf{Efforts:}$

As we know $L^1(\mathbb{R}) $ is closed under convolution. So is it enough to show that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for to see that their convolution is also in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?
Can you please let me know what conditions has to satisfy for the convolution be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487545)
\begin{split}
\widehat{g}(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|t|}e^{-ix t}\,dt
&=&\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{t}e^{-ix t}\,dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}e^{-ix t}\,dt\\
 &=&\left[ \frac{e^{(1-ix)t}}{1-ix} \right]_{-\infty}^0-\left[\frac{e^{-(1+ix)t}}{1+ix} \right]_{0}^{\infty}\\
&=&\frac{1}{1-ix}+\frac{1}{1+ix}\\
&=&\color{blue}{\frac{2}{x^2+1}\in  L^1(\Bbb R)}.
\end{split}

Therefore,  we have  that $\widehat{g}\in L^1$ and we know that  $\widehat{f} \in L^\infty$ (Since $f\in L^1$ ) hence $$\color{red}{\widehat{f*g}=\widehat{f}\displaystyle\widehat{g}  \in L^1}$$

**Proof of the claim above**
$$|\widehat{f}(a)|=\left|\int f(x)e^{-ixa}\, dx\right| \le \int \left|f(x)\, \right|dx =\|f\|_1 $$

that is $$\|\widehat{f}\|_{\infty}\le \|f\|_1 $$

Comment: So you are using $g(t) = e^{-|t|} \implies \hat{g}(\omega) = \frac{\pi}{1+\omega^2}$. More generally, you can say that $g \in  L^2, g'(t ) = -\text{sign}(t) e^{-|t|} \in  L^2 \implies \hat{g},
 \omega \hat{g} \in L^2 \implies (1+|\omega|)\hat{g} \in L^2$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz $\|g\|_{L^1} \le \|(1+|\omega|) g(\omega)\|_{L^2} \|\frac{1}{1+|\omega|}\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @reuns you are right. see the edit I have added the details

Comment: @GuyFsone Many thanks! Sorry can you please let me know why $\hat{f} \in L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @Nikita it is easy to see that:  $|\widehat{f}(a)|\le \|f\|_1$ for all a

Comment: @GuyFsone Thanks! Sorry can you please show me? I am new in this staff

Comment: @GuyFsone Many thanks! Very clever idea!

Comment: Why do all this? All you need is that the two functions are in $L^1,$ which is obvious, and that the convolution of two $L^1$ functions is in $L^1.$

Comment: @zhw. may I misunderstood the question but can you expalin this to me? "Verify whether the Fourier convolution of $f*g$'" this is what the OP wrote . It is note just convolution.

Comment: why a down vote here?

Comment: @zhw. Here is his attempt: $\textbf{Efforts:}$<p>
As we know $L_1(\mathbb{R}) $ is closed under convolution. So is it enough to show that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ for to see that their convolution is also in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$?
Can you please let me know what conditions has to satisfy for the convolution be in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$?<p>

Comment: @zhw. the above clearluy shows that the OP already knows what you are talking about

Comment: @zhw. thanks for removing your down vote

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the problem. I down voted you because of that misreading. I trivially edited your answer so I could change my vote, so now I upvoted you! Again, apologies.

Comment: @zhw. May be you explain to Jack now. what is the point