# Contour integration with absolute value

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to use contour integration to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{|x|e^{i\omega x}}{x^2+ a}dx \,,
$$
where $a>0$ and $\omega$ can take any real value. I am worried about the existence of the absolute value and I am not sure how to proceed.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** Contour integration might not be the way to go here (see comments). In any case, it is easy to see that the integral in question is also equal to
$$
2\int_0^\infty \frac{x \cos(\omega x)}{x^2+ a}dx \,,
$$
and I am wondering whether anyone can produce a solution regardless of the method used.

Comment: Can't you use the Fourrier transform?

Comment: You are correct that the absolute value is a problem. The residue theorem only holds for functions that are analytic everywhere inside the curve except for isolated singularities. The absolute value has more problems than just at $0$ here, as it can only be analytically extended to two functions ($x$ and $-x$) defined on disjoint regions in $\Bbb C$. To do this by contours would require additional trickery. Also, as the integrand is $O(1/|z|)$, the integral on the arc does not go to $0$ as $|z| \to \infty$, so contour integration is not the way to go here.

Comment: @GuyFsone This is essentially what I am trying to evaluate in the first place. I do not see how I can evaluate the integral using known Fourier transforms and its known properties.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for your answer! So, would the problems still exist if I split the integral to two, one from $-\infty$ to $0$  and one from $0$ to $\infty$? Then I could consider the cases $\omega>0$ and $\omega<0$ separately and design different contours for each case. However, your concluding remark worries me. Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487545

Comment: It should worry you. That is why I included the comment. Doing line integrals by contour requires that the part of the contour that is not your line be handled in some way - either by evaluating it in some fashion, or by making it go to $0$ in a limit. However, this one doesn't go to $0$, so unless you can find a way to evaluate the rest of the contour, you are stuck. And breaking it at $0$ means you have to figure out a contour from $0$.

Comment: Guy Fsone's link is for a slightly different integral, but it does point out that your integral is equal to $$2\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos(\omega x)}{x^2+a}dx$$since the imaginary part is an odd function. And this version is at least meromorphic. But again, to do it by contour requires coming up with a closed contour where you can make everything but $[0,\infty)$ go away or can handle in some other fashion.

Comment: @GuyFsone Thanks for the link. The integral there is very similar but not quite the same. I have tried to use the techniques and tricks used there to evaluate mine but without any success. Could you please give me more hints on how to obtain the solution? Plugging it in Mathematica gives a quite complex answer, which make suspect that it might not be as trivial as one would think. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. I am also completely stuck with contour integration, so not sure how to proceed there either. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: @JohnnyB I just realized that this integral cannot be compute using classical method. utilizing the parity it is equals to $$2\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos(\omega x)}{x^2+a}dx$$ but this depends on Si and Ci function. Whereas if one had sin in place of cos then this  would have been computable. This is a surprising artefact's. I  really learn something from this integral. sorry that I cannot help more. +1:)

Answer (score 1):

Let's treat it like a Fourier Transform, and use a number of table lookups and theorems.

Set $\omega = -2\pi s$,

$$\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\dfrac{|x|e^{i\omega x}}{x^2+a}}dx &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty{\dfrac{|x|e^{-2\pi is x}}{x^2+a}}dx \\
\\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{|x|}{x^2+a}\right\} \\
\\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{x\space\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{x^2+a}\right\}\\
\\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{x^2+a}\right\}*\mathscr{F}\left\{x\space\mathrm{sgn}(x)\right\} \\
\\
&= \dfrac{(2\pi)^2}{2\left(2\pi\sqrt{a}\right)}\mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{2\left(2\pi\sqrt{a}\right)}{(2\pi x)^2+\left(2\pi\sqrt{a}\right)^2}\right\}*-\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\mathscr{F}\left\{-2\pi i x\space\mathrm{sgn}(x)\right\} \\
\\
&= \dfrac{2\pi}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}|s|}*-\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\dfrac{d}{ds}\dfrac{1}{i\pi s} \\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}|s|}*\dfrac{d}{ds}\dfrac{1}{\pi s} \\
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}|s|}*-\dfrac{1}{\pi s^2} \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}|\tau|}}{(s-\tau)^2}}d\tau \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{0} {\dfrac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}\tau}}{(s-\tau)^2}}d\tau +\int_{0}^{\infty} {\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}\tau}}{(s-\tau)^2}}d\tau\right] \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{-s} {\dfrac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}(t+s)}}{t^2}}dt +\int_{-s}^{\infty} {\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}(t+s)}}{t^2}}dt\right] \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\left[e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}s}\int_{-\infty}^{-s} {\dfrac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t^2}}dt +e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}s}\int_{-s}^{\infty} {\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t^2}}dt\right] \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\left[e^{-\sqrt{a}\omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\omega}{2\pi}} {\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{e^{2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t}}dt +e^{\sqrt{a}\omega}\int_{\frac{\omega}{2\pi}}^{\infty} {\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t}}dt\right] \\
\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{a}}\left[e^{-\sqrt{a}\omega}\int_{-\frac{\omega}{2\pi}}^\infty {\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t}}dt +e^{\sqrt{a}\omega}\int_{\frac{\omega}{2\pi}}^{\infty} {\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{a}t}}{t}}dt\right] \\
\\
\end{align*}$$

So those integrals are looking really close to being an integration by parts resulting in an expression involving the Exponential Integral function, and Wolfram Alpha confirms the indefinite integral results include the Exponential Integral function.

I think getting to the final result from here is straightforward, but tedious.