# How to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}$.

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I want to prove that for $t,a>0$:
$$f_a(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}$$
It is easy to prove that 
$$f_a''(t)=a^2f_a(t),$$
then
$$f_a(t)=c_1e^{at}+c_2e^{-at}$$
Cleary $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}f_a(t)=0$ and therefore $c_1=0$. But I could not justify that $c_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your answer can be generalized to any t and a

Comment: From $f_a(0)=0$ it would follow that $c_1+c_2=0$. Probably you meant $t\rightarrow+\infty $.

Comment: A direct calculation of the integral using a residue added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c_{2}=f_{0}(1)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+1}dx=\tan^{-1}x\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: ¿Why is $c_2$ independent of $a$?

Comment: I had a rough calculation. By writing $c_{2}=c_{2}(a)$ which is dependent of $a>0$, then by change of variable one has $c_{2}(a)=c_{2}(1)$ and $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^{+}}c_{2}(a)=c_{2}(0)$.

Comment: If instead of $\cos(ax)$ I put $\sin(ax)$ then $c_2=$?

Comment: Then it is an entirely different question, the differential equation then would be different, must the two $c_{2}(a)$ have something to do?

Comment: The result is $c_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the equation is the same. That says my exercise.

Comment: Then use the same trick, no?

Comment: Another thing, for asumption $a\neq 0$. Still $c_2=\pi/2$?

Comment: You see, $\cos(ax)=\cos(-ax)$, so $a>0$ is not crucial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74972/discussion-between-andres-felipe-and-user284331).

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective is the change of variables Enforcing $x=yt$ then [from this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487545) we get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^2\cos(aty)}{t^2(y^2+1)}dy=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-|at|} $$

Answer (score 1):

There is another nice solution going through the complex via a residue:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx = \frac{1}{2}Re\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}e^{iax}dx \right)$$
Here I wrote $Re$ for real part, but it turns out that the integral on the right is real:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}e^{iax}dx = 2\pi iRes_{it}\left( \frac{t}{z^2+t^2}e^{iaz}\right) = 2\pi i \lim_{z\rightarrow it}\left( \frac{t(z-it)}{(z+it)(z-it)}e^{iaz}\right)= 2\pi i\frac{t}{2it}e^{-at} = \pi e^{-at}$$
All together:
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{x^2+t^2}\cos(ax)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-at}$$